# Unable to deploy LWC in org

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to deploy a LWC in my dev org but unable to do so because of an error: 'Unable to find Apex action method referenced as 'RetrieveContacts.getContactList.' I have checked and the apex class is already available in the org

Markup:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-datatable
        key-field= "Id"
        data={records}
        columns={columns}
        >
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/RetrieveContacts.getContactList';

export default class ContactLightningDataTable extends LightningElement {
    
records;
errormessage;
columns = [
    {
    label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'FirstName',
    label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'LastName',
    label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone',
    label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email'
    }
];

 @wire(getContacts)
 contacts(data, error){
    if(data){
        this.records = data;
    }
    else{
        this.errormessage = error;
    }
 }

}
```

Meta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class RetrieveContacts {
    public static List<Contact> getContactList() {
        return [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I think you are missing the `@AuraEnabled` annotation on your apex method

Comment: Ohh yes! Thanks @McCubo